# MySQL migrate data from 5.1 to 5.6 - threats

Tags: mysql, migrate

I do plan to migrate the database from version 5.1 to version 5.6.
I want to do this by using mysqldump:

1. Export (by mysqldump) data from MySQL DB 5.1 to sql file,
2. Import (by mysqldump) this sql file that MySQL 5.6 database,

Do not have a complex database that migration can be associated with some risks?
What to look for?

I can not do update database from 5.1 a 5.6, because I can not stop the production base at this point.

Comment: Use a Virtual Machine (Virtual Box, VM Ware, OpenVZ,...) and try it. The most significant is the order in which you import things, because of references (foreign keys) I guess. Every setup and scheme is different, so you must try it in a test environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking it is safe (and supported) to upgrade using mysqldump.

My best suggestion is to use mysqldump from MyQSL 5.6 against the 5.1 server, as newer versions have quite a few fixes to ensure the correct order when dumping foreign keys and other bits and pieces.  Your 5.1 version may have these fixes already, but using the newer version won't hurt in any case.

Ensure you run mysql_upgrade after importing the database into 5.6, and then restart the server, as per the MySQL upgrade guide:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading.html

Alternatively if you can update in two steps, you can do a in-place binary upgrade by first upgrading to 5.5.x before 5.6.x, ensuring to run mysql_upgrade during both steps.